# How do I change/add swift version in my NATIVESCRIPT PROJECT?

Tags: swift, xcode, nativescript

So I am trying to run my project from windows. I transferred it to my MacOs to build the iOS part but for some reason this error keeps on popping up.

error:

```
Xcode build...
2020-06-05 18:35:52.082 xcodebuild[5562:73611]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-16131/DVTFoundation/Utilities/DVTFileSystemUtilities.mm:142
Details:  lstat('/Volumes/STORAGE/test/fagck-app/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BEMCheckBox/BEMCheckBox.framework') failed with errno 2 (No such file or directory)
Function: DVTRecursiveMkdirResult dvt_recursiveMkdir_returningErrorString(NSString *__strong, NSString *__autoreleasing *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f928cba1110>{number = 14, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.
** BUILD FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: 0873EB86-B9E3-43E3-9E63-14D6061DC079. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.
```

package.json:
dependencies: {
//this helped me move forward on compilation but still same error after further compile
    "nativescript-swift-3.0": "^1.0.0",
}

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You are trying to compile Swift 3.0, which isn't supported by the current Xcode versions. `nativescript-swift-3.0` you should probably update that.

Comment: @DávidPásztor hi, before installing that plugin, I already have the error. after installing that plugin, it helped me go further in the compiling process but the same error would still come up